# external wordpress pages using wp-blog-header

Tags: php, wp-load.php

I am setting up a few sections of a website external to the core wordpress installation, but I still want to use the built in wpdb functions, and/or header files from wordpress.

I follow the instructions outlined in wordpress, setting up my headers:

```
 <?
 require('../cms/wp-blog-header.php');
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);    
 .
 . ?>
```

Everything works great. I can use wordpress' built in functionality while extending my site to use other functionality.

In one case, the file is outside of my wordpress directory. In another case, the file is nested in a folder in the root of my wordpress directory.

However, when loading the page in question, I get a 404 in the Net Panel of my inspector of the exact page I'm loading, like Wordpress can't find the page, but since it's a real php page, of course it loads. Most importantly, the pages fail to load using IE8.

Does anyone have insight to this issue?

[Example Link](http://74.54.218.130/~paragon/homes/homes.php)

More links and screenshots available, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution Found! Thanks to [these guys](http://www.adrogen.com/blog/wordpress-wp-blog-headerphp-causes-404-in-ie/)

```
require('../cms/wp-config.php');  
$wp->init();  
$wp->parse_request();  
$wp->query_posts();  
$wp->register_globals();
```

The key is, don't use wp-blog-header, but this code instead.

Comment: Working like a charm in 2019.

Answer (score 4):

consider including `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`

You can also "force" a 200 response using `status_header(200);` although, depending on how you code your site, this could interfere with sending legitimate 404s.